# Ожидание выполнения метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом проверить выполнение метода и после его завершения запустить другой метод?

```
try
        {
            bool needUpdate = await _updater.CheckUpdateAsync();
            if (needUpdate)
            { _updater.Update(); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Logger.Current.AppendException(ex); }

        try
        {
            bool needUpdate = await _updater2.CheckUpdateAsync();
            if (needUpdate)
            { _updater2.Update(); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Logger.Current.AppendException(ex); }
```

Смысл таков: Если требуется обновление - начать процедуру.  Но в этом коде я обращаюсь сразу к двум методам, как реализовать проверку типа - если метод выполняется то второй метод ожидает выполнение первого и только после запускается?

Comment: Дополню - после завершения метода я устанавливаю статус "UpdateState.Completed:"

Comment: А что именно делает Update(): дожидается синхронно конца обновления, или только запускает его? Если это ваша функция, покажите код.

Comment: _updater.Update()  запускает метод обновления, из класса WowUpdater. код слишком большой ибо телодвижений очень много

Comment: Окей, но этот метод ваш? У вас есть над ним контроль?

Comment: Ну да, я же вызываю этот метод в классе апдейтера из главной формы

Comment: Не, я имею в виду, вы можете поменять код этого метода? И ещё, этот метод блокирующий или нет? (То есть, можно ли его запускать в UI-потоке?)

Comment: Да, я могу изменить код этого класса и метода в том числе, по поводу блокирующий или нет - не совсем поняла

Comment: Окей, тогда сейчас сделаем :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий подход. Нам нужен асинхронный метод, который завершится вместе с завершением обновления. Его можно переделать из `Update`:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync()
{
    if (_currentState != UpdateState.None)
        return; // это не совсем правильно, тут надо дождаться окончания текущего обновления

    _currentState = UpdateState.Started;
    Logger.Current.AppendText("Began update game client");
    //Запускаем выполнение кода в потоке из пула потоков.
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Уведомляем подписчиков, что обновление запущено.
        OnUpdateStateChanged(UpdateState.Started);

        //Скачиваем патч лист
        Logger.Current.AppendText("Download patchlist");
```

и далее как было.

Теперь можно написать так:

```
async Task CheckAndUpdate(WowUpdater updater)
{
    try
    {
        bool needUpdate = await updater.CheckUpdateAsync();
        if (needUpdate)
        { await updater.UpdateAsync(); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Logger.Current.AppendException(ex); }
}
```

И дальше просто

```
await CheckAndUpdate(_updater);
await CheckAndUpdate(_updater2);
```

и т. д.

Comment: http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/07/b2555d53885b1b42216b588ab11a897e.png       В класс я поместила Ваш код, по итогу такие ошибки  -  " The name 'updateCompletion' does not exist in the current context "   и   "No overload for method 'Update' takes 1 arguments 
"
Если Вам будет удобно, мы можем пообщаться в скайпе, мне очень неловко разводить тут чат ((

Comment: @Елизавета: Я с телефона, там всё равно сложно быстро печатать. Смотрите, вам нужно добавить аргумент в Update, чтобы скомпилировалось. И протянуть его до точки, где вызывается SetResult.

Comment: @Елизавета: Хорошо, напишу, когда доберусь до компьютера.

Comment: @Елизавета: Заходите в чат, я создал комнату: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43125/checkandupdate

Comment: Жду Вас в чате, проблему описала